# Code arithmetic expression in a binary tree

Tags: algorithms, trees, binary-trees

How to present (code into) an expression consisting of brackets and following operations: +, -, / and * into a binary tree. Then, I need to write an algorithm that will derive that very tree.

Any hints or suggestions on how to do this?

I've tried placing brackets and operands into the leaves, but I'm not even precisely sure on what to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to deal with operator precedence? (For example in the expression 1 + 2 * 3, would the expected answer be 7 or 9?)

Comment: It is left up to us. My guess with operator precedence would be better.

Comment: The object you're trying to construct is a [parse tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree). But I'm voting to close this question as too broad: essentially, you're asking us to write a chapter of a compilers textbook for you. For that reason, I also think it's a crappy exercise to set somebody (unless it came in your compilers course _after_ all that stuff had been taught and you skipped the classes/weren't paying attention/whatever).